# Connect two connected clients to each other in python

Tags: python, sockets, file-io, io

I'm attempting to use a central server like a proxy server in python, such that when one computer asks the server for another computer linked to the server under the user's account.

In python, I'm connecting the clients to the server with a socket connection, and I'm attempting to get a file from client A to client B without storing the file on the central server.

The clients can use the central server to pass the file, but I'd prefer to create a connection between the two clients, only using the server to keep a list of the user's client systems.

Ultimately, I'm flexible in this, so long as the file is not stored on the server any longer than necessary to transfer the file. I never want the file saved to the disk.

Comment: Unless the clients will always be able to communicate with each other directly, data will have to pass thought the server. This I the case I'm guessing. You could always just read line the data coming in, then write it back out of the sockets. But on another note, why reinvent the wheel? Why not use scp and ssh port forwarding?

Comment: you don't need to save the file. just read from one client 1024 bytes, send them to the other and so on.

Comment: @korylprince I don't want to rely on having an ssh server installed on each client.

Comment: @IonutHulub If at all possible, it would lighten my network load a ton if I could bypass moving files through the server, even temporarily. Some of these files could get very large as the user base grows, this would become the main bottleneck.

Comment: Do the clients have a direct connection? As in could you open a socket from one client to another?

Comment: Not to each other, only to the server. I'm trying to figure out how to put them in contact despite them being entirely unaware of each other until the server tells them they exist.